# Using ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute breaks XML Comment

Tags: c#, code-coverage, comments

Im using Visual Studio 2010 with c#.

I'm using XML documentation in my project and successfully added comments.
Successfully means there are noch compilerwarnings about missing XML comments.

Then I checked the codevoverage for my project and started to exclude some files from codecoverage calculation with System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.[ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute]

I did it in the following way:

```
...
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace MyAppp
{
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute]
/// <summary>My comment</summary>
public partial class FDB_PolicyGruppen : Form
{ ...
}
}
```

The problem is, as soon as I put [ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute] before a comment, I receive the warnings
CS1591: Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member
or 
CS1587 XML comment is not placed on a valid language element.

Comment: Have you tried putting the comment above the attribute rather than below?

Comment: Spoke too soon. Now my codecoverage has gone down.
That means, that [ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute] is ignored after XML comment.

Comment: Hmm that sounds like a bug in whatever you are using to measure code coverage or you have made a copy and paste error hwne juggling things about, i can see how positioning of the comments might affect something that is looking for comments but something measuring code coverage shouldn't even notice comments wherever they happen to be.

Comment: I opened a bug report at microsoft connect. Feedback/Bug ID 685518

[Bug-Report at microsoft connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=685518)

Comment: The bug was closed as not reproducible on Microsoft Connect - as such @BenRobinson should make an answer from his comment as that fixed the issue

Comment: @BenRobinson It's actually correct; the XML comments are supposed to appear above the declaration of the method, class or struct they are applied to, and a declaration of a method, class or struct includes any attributes applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm that sounds like a bug in whatever you are using to measure code coverage or you have made a copy and paste error hwne juggling things about, i can see how positioning of the comments might affect something that is looking for comments but something measuring code coverage shouldn't even notice comments wherever they happen to be.